# Horizontal scrolling to a specific element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I made the following component in Angular.
It's basically a kind of tree component.

[image: Tree]

Please note the following:

- The tree has several branches.
- It consists of nodes in alternating colors.
- And the selected node is marked by a blue dot.
- The tree does not fit the screen, that's why **there's a horizontal scroll bar.**
- Each node has a unique id (i.e. `<div id="...">`)

This component works fine, however. **I don't know how to add the following feature:**

- When the focus changes, (in other words, a different node becomes active), I want this node always to be visible on the screen. That means that **the webbrowser has to scroll to the left or right**, automatically whenever a node is selected. It has to scroll or jump until the specific `<div>` is visible.

How can this be done using javascript or typescript ?

## EDIT:

I want to use this javascript is the base for better navigation tools.

- button to move back and forth in the tree
- button to jump 10 nodes to left/right.
- button to jump to the back.
- button to jump to the start.

Also when a new node is added to the back of the tree, right now the user has to scroll all the way to the right, manually. I want it to be visible immediatly, automatically.

Those are my real objectives :)

Comment: You should be using the styles as `max-width : <<value>>; overflow:scroll`

Comment: @Aravind my question is not about making the scroll bar visible, it's about some piece of javascript that actually moves the scroll bar, until the required part of the screen is visible. e.g. When a new node is added to the back of the tree, I want this node to be visible. But right now the user has to scroll manually to the right, which is not that user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If the only scroll mechanism you need is the automatic one, I would avoid trying to use the browser's built in scrolling mechanism altogether and just use ElementRef of the node to get its horizontal position relative to its container, and then apply a CSS 'translate' to move it as needed. It will be much easier this way to have it look "nice" with CSS transitions and animations. But if you would still need manual scroll behavior (i.e, the user still needs to be able to scroll with a scrollbar) youd have to program a scrollbar directive / solution as well, which may end up being more effort than the problem demands.

This page has a sort of hacky workaround for horizontal scrolling - https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/

The problem for me in the past with 'scrollTop' and 'scrollLeft' is you can't apply transitions to those attributes, so they end up looking very jerky without implementing custom easing functions in javascript.